# ANDROID Studio: Adding a View dynamically

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a PieChart (my own class) to an existing linearLayout

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_available_option, container, false);

            LinearLayout linearLayoutHorizontalContainerForPieChart =
                 (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linerLayoutHorizontalContainerForPieChart);
            linearLayoutHorizontalContainerForPieChart.addView(new PieChart(container));

            return rootView;
        }
```

From all the examples I've come across online it appears that it should be done within the onCreateView method. BUt it gives me an error, indicating that " *' this' cannot be referenced from a static object*".

So, where do I do this kind of initialization of dynamically adding a new object to and existing object?

Comment: can you show the full fragment class?

Answer (score 0):

I realized I'm trying to add it in the OnCreateView instead of the onCreate of the Activity.

My goof.